# Running out of gas before draining target completely using reentrancy exploit

Tags: out-of-gas, reentrant-attacks

[image]

Recreated the reentrancy exploit (somewhat) successfully on ganache.  Unable to drain the target completely owing to out-of-gas error occuring midway.  Hence have currently limited the drain.
Though a custom 'gas' value can be passed with 'call', thinking through on that large input gas value that not only provides a +ve ROI but also meets the networks upper limit.
Is reentrancy still a vulnerability and is it worth the gas investment?
Thoughts please?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After unsuccessfully playing around with various different gas sizes & after unsuccessfully trying different gas estimations, I focused on the functioning of 'call'.
Call returns a true or false based on whether or not it succeeded.
I simply removed this check - stopped caring what call returned.  Just kept on with the reentrancy.  Commented out the check.

```
//require(success, '*TB.loot.withdraw().FAILED*');
```

And that did the trick.  Even though success was coming as false, after removing the check, the fallback kept on getting triggered and I was able to drain the target contract successfully - just leaving it with 1 ETH.

Looks like call invocations carry forward sufficient gas for iterative executions.  Haven't checked with an extremely large ETH amount.  Might be a good idea to check the max gas consumption leading to OOG exception.

For now, success!